# MSAL popup: Is it possible to display only the users from that specific tenant

Tags: azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I've used domain_hint: "example.com" and it does list the accounts that match that domain but is there a way to list all the accounts under the provided tenant ID?

Answer (score 0):

You can list all users in your tenant using MS Graph.

Please go through [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

For example below java script will return all users of particular tenant,

```
const options = {
    authProvider,
};

const client = Client.init(options);

let res = await client.api('/users').get();
```

Make sure your MSAL token contains minimum `User.ReadBasic.All` permission to achieve this.